# Windows XP mode suddenly claims hardware does not support virtualization

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

I have a PC system with a AMD X2 dual-core processor and Windows 7 professional.

I am using Windows XP mode to use a scanner that doesn't have Windows 7 drivers. This used to work fine.

But all of a sudden, Microsoft Virtual PC refuses to start up with a message approximately saying (translated from German so not verbatim):

> Windows XP mode could not be initialized because of a mismatch in the host processor type, or because hardware virtualization is not supported.

I have not changed my processor configuration, nor anything else on the system.

I have checked the BIOS and the "Virtualization support" switch was turned off. I turned it on, but to no avail.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is caused by a corrupt hibernation file.

I had the same problem and was able to fix it using [this article](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistawu/thread/eac629ec-f789-477e-b69a-ab175ccb8d3a).

These are the steps from the article I used to fix my problem.

> 1. Click on Start and click on computer.
> 2. Go to the following location:
>      C:\Users\ (Username)\ AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows
>      Virtual PC\Virtual Machines directory
> 3. You’ll find a .VSV file in the Virtual Machines Directory.
> 4. Rename the file. 
>      For example: If the file name is VM.vsv, rename it toVM.old
> 5. Close all the windows and restart Virtual Machine. You should be able to
>      run it without having any problem.